# How does Engine Room work with Roslin’s Religious Visions ability?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, pegasus

If the Engine Room is used during Roslin's turn, would either Crisis Card she chooses automatically have a jump icon, or just the first one drawn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I submitted this question to Fantasy Flight support. Here's the response:

> For the purposes of using the Engine Room during Roslin's turn, whichever card Roslin chooses to resolve is treated as "the next Crisis Card drawn." Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 0):

Just from looking at the rules and cards...

Engine Room specifically refers to the next card **drawn**, not played.

Thus Roslin choose between two cards, but the first one drawn would now have a jump icon on it.

I can't find an errata/ruling about that particular interaction.

Comment: The problem with that ruling is that now the person playing Roslin has to be trusted to keep track of which one gets the jump icon (since no one else gets to see the cards), or some ceremony needs to be enforced like: keep the first card drawn in your right hand and the second card drawn in your left, look at them both and then put one on the bottom and play the other. Not saying it's the wrong ruling, it just complicates things.

Comment: @Todd - if the complexity is a problem, house rule it away.  Its kind of like the "rule 0" of boardgames.